# C++ Abstract Base Class with pure virtual operator+ function

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, operator-overloading, abstract-class

Let's say I am creating an Abstract Base Class for the purpose of defining a public interface.  I want operator+ to be a part of this public interface.  It would seem that this is not possible in C++ or that I am missing something.

For example, suppose the code below is a .h file declaring the public interface for an abstract base class named IAbstract.  This code does not compile because I cannot declare a function that returns an instance of an abstract base class.  This compile error makes sense, but what I don't understand is this: **Is there any way to guarantee operator+ will exist in the public interface of IAbstract?**

```
#include <iostream>

// An abstract base class
class IAbstract
{
public:
    IAbstract(int value);
    virtual ~IAbstract() {}
    virtual int SomeOtherFunction() =0;

    //This is ok
    virtual IAbstract& operator++() =0;

    //This will not compile
    virtual const IAbstract operator+(const IAbstract& rhs) =0;
    //Xcode5 says "Semantic Issue: Return type 'IAbstract' is an abstract class"
};
```

Comment: Returning by value makes no sense for polymorphic hierarchies.

Comment: How would you implement an operator+ function that returns a reference?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible guarantee operator+ will exist in the public interface of IAbstract-derived classes because you cannot properly declare operator+ as a pure virtual function.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the return by value problem, the really problem with your dessign is **the way that the C++ language works**.

Object oriented languages like Java defines and transmit functionality through class hierarchies, interfaces, and polymorphism. Your code is the typical example of that.
**C++ does not work in that way**. C++ defines functionality through abstract concepts, and classes only need to fulfill this concepts to be usable in a certain way. How/if a class follows or implements a certain concept depends on its behavior, the implementation of certain functions (Like overloaded operators), etc.

So the C++ way to do what you are trying to achieve is to **overload the required operators in a generic way, to ensure all classes that would implement the concept works with it**.
In other words, if you are trying to make an addable concept, that is, represent things that could be added with others, a class only have to overload `operator+`. If a class overloads `operator+` its addable. Just simple.

Here is another example: The classic implementation of [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
template<typename IT , typename DEST_IT>
void copy( IT begin , IT end , DEST_IT dest_begin )
{
    while( begin != end )
        *dest_begin++ = *begin++;
}
```

In that implementation, whats the type of `begin` and `end`? **Simple answer: We don't know. Could be anything.** But could be anything that **must fulfill the requirements of our function**, that is: *Is dereferenciable, incrementable, and comparable*. In other words: **Its an** ***iterable***  **type**. A type that works (And seems like) an iterator.

So `std::copy()` works with any ranges represented by iterable things. Could be arrays:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,2,3 };
    int b[3];

    int* begin_a = &a[0];
    int* end_a   = &a[2];
    int* begin_b = &b[0];

    //Pointers are an iterable thing, right?:
    std::copy( begin_a , end_a , begin_b );

    //Or just the common generic way (Which does exactly the same):
    std::copy( std::begin( a ) , std::end( a ) , std::begin( a ) );
}
```

Vectors, lists, etc:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> b;

    //Wooh, the code is exactly the same! Thats why templates are cool.
    std::copy( std::begin( a ) , std::end( a ) , std::begin( a ) );
}
```

More freaking things, like iterators to walk through an stream:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3 };

    //Copy a vector to the standard output? Yes we can!
    std::copy( std::begin( a ) , std::end( a ) , std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout , "\n" ) );
}
```

> 1
>   2
>   3

And your own classes:

```
struct numeric_iterator
{
    int value;

    numeric_iterator( int initial_value = 0 ) : value( initial_value ) {}

    //numeric_iterator is an iterable thing because...

    //... its dereferenciable
    int operator*() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    //... its incrementable
    numeric_iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++value;
        return *this;
    }

    numeric_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        numeric_iterator copy( *this );

        ++(*this);

        return copy;
    }

    //... and its comparable
    friend bool operator==( const numeric_iterator& lhs , const numeric_iterator& lhs )
    {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value;
    }

    friend bool operator!=( const numeric_iterator& lhs , const numeric_iterator& lhs )
    {
        return !( lhs == rhs );
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Tah dah!
    std::copy( numeric_iterator( -4 ) , 
               numeric_iterator(  5 ) , 
               std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout , " " ) 
             );
}
```

> -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: I'm not sure this answer's my question, sorry.  Can an abstract base class define a pure virtual operator+ function?

Comment: @MatthewBriggs You can, but you shouldn't. Could view my answer not as a direct answer to your question, but as an overview of why you shouldn't do that in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is:

```
virtual const IAbstract operator+(const IAbstract& rhs) =0;
```

That method returns by value, thus copying and creating an object of type IAbstract, which is not allowed.  You should change to:

```
virtual const IAbstract& operator+(const IAbstract& rhs) =0;
```

That seems to be your intent but an easy oversight.

Comment: I don't see how operator+ could be implemented to return a reference.  It cannot return *this because because *this should not be changed by the function.  If I return a reference to a temp object, that would be bad because it goes out of scope at the functions closing brace.  If I return a reference to a heap object that would be ugly as well.  I'm just not seeing how operator+ can return a reference.

Comment: Returning *this from member functions such as operator+ is actually how it is typically implemented.  The method is not const so "this" is freely available to be modified.  Also, a common design paradigm is to implement these type of operators ( +, <<, etc.) as non-member functions.  This would be a fundamental design change for you that could significantly change how the features are implemented.

Comment: @MatthewBriggs thats because operators are not dessigned to be overloaded polymorphically. Even if you use the member version of binary operators (Which are just shorthands to the non-member binary versions) you should never return `*this`.

Comment: @TimDave Are you confusing operator++ with operator+? C = A+B should not alter A or B.

Comment: @MatthewBriggs I am referring to operator +.  Ideally, you would not modify this but there is little choice when using the member function.  While it is preferred to not modify A in C=A+B, you must to return a reference.  If you did not return a reference the code can quickly turn inefficient.  This is a reason why a non-member function is preferred.

Comment: @Manu343726 There is nothing inherently wrong about returning *this.  It can be misused just like any mechanism.  How would you implement the assignment operator (=) or operator++?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have: `IAbstract variable` and you can never actually have an `IAbstract`, only pointers to it (or references).

It is annoyed because somewhere you try and deal with a `IAbstract`.

It wants `IAbstract*` or `IAbstract&` or `IAbstract&&` which are all fine (in some form (const and volatile, so forth)).

There you go, you are returning `IAbstract` from operator++, which makes no sense, because you can **never** have a `IAbstract`, just look at something as one.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to encapsulate the abstract base class, inside a regular type. The solution requires that there is a clone method

```
class AbstractNumericType
{
public:
    virtual AbstractNumericType& operator+=(AbstractNumericType const& other) = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractNumeric> clone() = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractNumericType() = default;
};
```

```
class NumericType
{
public:
    template<class Something>
    NumericType(Something value):m_obj{createNumber(value)}
    {}

    NumericType(NumericType const& other): m_obj{other.m_obj->clone()}
    {}

    NumericType operator+(NumericType const& other) const
    {
         auto ret = *this;
         (*ret.m_obj) += (*other.m_obj);
         return ret;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractNumericType> m_obj;
};
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e4v1Tr

The real problem here is how you can implement `operator+=` when you do not have the concrete type available. You could add multiple overloads (like visitor pattern), or you could use a type switch based on rtti. None of these solutions is really good.